# what happens if the argument types of a function prototype are omitted (in c)

Tags: c

What happens
during the compilation and Linking process if the argument types are omitted(considering that the defined function takes arguments)? 
Will the compiler just mark the prototype with missing argument as a syntax error?

**Edit**

so I found out it builds and runs

```
#include<stdio.h>

float addf(a,b); // even without a,b it runs

    int main(){

        float input1 = 10.0;  
        float input2 = 20.0;

        printf("%f + %f = %f", input1, input2, addf(input1, input2) );

        getchar();

        return 0;
    }

float addf(float a, float b){

    return a + b;
}
```

---

```
result : 10.000000 + 20.000000 = 2.562500
```

Any idea why is it executed this way?

Comment: Using older rules they defaulted to be of type `int`.

Comment: Why the question? Just provide the prototype. When is this ever relevant?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are prototypes required for all functions in C89, C90 or C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434763/are-prototypes-required-for-all-functions-in-c89-c90-or-c99) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575153/must-declare-function-prototype-in-c)

Comment: @Henno Brandsma I'm just curious

Answer (score 1):

The phrasing in the question is in error. You cannot omit the types in a *function prototype*. If you omit the types in function definition, declaration, it doesn't **have a prototype**. Only the declaration, definition that contains function types (be it just `void`) has **a prototype**.

---

When you do omit the types in a function definition, you get the old style* *declaration-list*. You must specify types for the parameters *before* the function body, [an example of which can be seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816001/weird-c-function-declaration). The caller cannot know how to call this correctly, and the compiler cannot check. Scalar types are subject to *default argument promotions*, just like the variable-argument part of the prototyped functions.

---

As for the code in your question, it is *not* standards-compliant - in fact, there are 2 grave errors:

```
float addf(a,b); // even without a,b it runs
```

Is an incorrect declaration, that is not allowed by C - you must write

```
float addf();  // empty parentheses
```

and b, the actual parameters must be of type **double**, because the default argument promotions will convert them.